# iOS Modal ViewController with Transparent BG and Opaque Foreground

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I am trying to create a Modal View in XCode Storyboard with background semi-transparent. On this view I have placed a `TableView` which I want to appear with opaque background. But unfortunately, both are appearing either semi-transparent or opaque.

Is there any workaround to this?

P.S. I am using Swift as a programming language.

Answer (score -1):

Don't make the tableview a child view of your transparent view,your view hierarchy should be like
View
  TransparentView
TableView

Comment: can you please explain the reason behind down voting.Thanks